# Is there a quick way to add an image to all products in a WooCommerce store?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gallery

I have an image which mentions details about free delivery which I would like to add as an image to all of the products in a WooCommerce store. I don't want it to be the main image, I want it to be one of the images in the gallery for each product.

Is there a quick way to do this using an SQL script in PHPMyAdmin, or a plugin? Or will I have to manually add the image to each product via WooCommerce?